# How can I make a program runnable from the commandline without typing its full path?

Tags: windows, command-line

I can best explain my question with an example. I recently downloaded Python for Windows, installed to C:\Python. So if I'm in folder X that contains myscript.py, and I want to invoke it, I have to call this:

```
> C:\Python\python.exe myscript.py
```

But it would be super-cool if I could just do this, from within *any* folder:

```
> python myscript.py
```

How do I make that "global"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to add the path **C:\Python** to your *Path* Environment Variable which can be modified from the **Advanced** tab of the *System Properties* control panel.

[image]

Comment: I'm clicking on the buttons in your answer but they don't work, please advise :)

Comment: @OrbMan You almost made me snarf Diet DP.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution would be to add an entry to the registry:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\python.exe
```

and then set the `(default)` value of that to the path (+ program name) where your python.exe resides, e.g. `C:\Python\Python.exe`.

That way, you can call python.exe from anywhere - no path or other stuff needed.

Marc

Comment: All applications I write have installers that adds an app path.

Answer (score 4):

To eliminate the need to type `python` before your script, you can do the following:

1. Add `python.exe` to your system PATH environment variable, if it's not already there.
2. Add `;.py` to the end of your PATHEXT system environment variable.

Then, instead of typing

```
> C:\Python\python.exe myscript.py
```

or

```
> python myscript.py
```

you can just type

```
> myscript.py
```

Comment: I couldn't remember how to make all the .py files in my C:\Python\Scripts folder global. 
This did it.